# Using pagination with multiple loops causes it to break

Tags: categories, permalinks, loop, pagination

I'm have two loops on my index page. One fetches the latest posts from the 'work' category and the other fetches the latest from the 'blog' category. (see below)

I am also using a plugin called WP-PageNavi - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/. I only want the pagination on the blog section which I have at the moment and it works fine for that.

The problem is that when I click on to page 2 or 3 on the pagination the 'work' section also goes to the next page but there isnt enough posts so i see the "sorry, no posts" message.

How do i get the pagination to just affect the 'blog' section?

The other problem is that when I goto the 'blog' category page and click on the pagination there (or the 'view older posts', i tried both) it sends me to this url

```
http://localhost:8888/blog/page/2/
```

which results in a 404 as it is inserting 'blog' in the url. But if i remove 'blog' so goto

```
http://localhost:8888/page/2/
```

It then sends me to the index page and using the pagination on the index page.

If it helps my permalink structure is:

```
 /%category%/%postname%/
```

Here is my code...

First Loop for 'work' section:

```
<?php query_posts ($query_string . '&category_name=work'); ?>

 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="grid_4 latest-work">

        <?php

        // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            the_post_thumbnail('latest-work');  // Other resolutions
        } else {
            //No featured image supplied so use default.
        ?>

            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/default.png" width="300" height="200"/>

        <?php   }   ?>

        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <p class="client-name"><?php $key="client"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?></p>

    </div>

 <!-- Stop The Loop (but note the "else:" - see next line). -->
 <?php endwhile; else: ?>

 <p class="grid_12" style="margin-top:20px;">Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>

 <!-- REALLY stop The Loop. -->
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Second loop for 'Blog' section:

```
<?php query_posts( array( 'cat' => 6, 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ) ); ?>

<!-- Start the Loop. -->
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="what-moves-us" >

        <div class="home-blog-content">
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <a class="readmore" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="blog-featured-image">
            <?php

            // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail('latest-work');  // Other resolutions
            } else {
                //No featured image supplied so use default.
            ?> 
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/default.png" width="300" height="200"/>
            <?php   }   ?>
        </div>

    </div>

 <?php endwhile; else: ?>

 <p class="grid_12" style="margin:20px 0 0 0;">Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>

 <!-- REALLY stop The Loop. -->
 <?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem can be solved by changing the query_posts in your work section. Replace `'&category_name=work'` with `'&category_name=work&paged=1&posts_per_page=-1'`

For the second problem, why not use the category template itself in place of `index.php`?

As a side note, you should not use `query_posts` for this use case. In place of that you should use a new `WP_Query` object for the work loop & `pre_get_posts` filter for the main loop

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, what do you mean by use the category template in place of index.php? I have decided to remove the pagination from index now and just show the latest 3 posts. So my only problem is that on the category page getting it to stay on that page but paginate.

Comment: I mean creating a file category-6.php. see http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png